# ie7 breaks slider and lightbox2

Tags: internet-explorer-7, slider, lightbox

I am currently developing a site for a client (http://184.168.136.225/).  Having some issues with IE7 and the homepage slider as well as the products pages lightbox.

The slider is suppose to show and image on the left and a caption with a title, small copy and link button.  There is a progress bar that shows the time until the next slide.  This works fine in all browsers but IE7 - the images slide, but the text area does not fade in. I think I used infinite carousel for this.

The lightbox uses  lightbox2 (http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/).  I simply doesn't work in IE7. This is important because the client needs this to work because it displays a logo which gives them credit for their co-op.

Help on either would be appreciated, help on both would make my day.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: so I have fixed the slider with a css solution that is not an identical effect but close enough that it will work.  So the only remaining issue would be lightbox2 in IE7 which is simply not working.  Again any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Solved this issue for anyone having problems with lightbox2 in IE7, my problem was solved by deleting an extra js that I was not using and forgot to remove.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this issue for anyone having problems with lightbox2 in IE7:

It was solved by deleting an extra js that I was not using and forgot to remove.